# How to get saved password from POP3 account in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail

I have set up a POP3 mail account (Yahoo) in Gmail to send and receive my Yahoo messages from there. Everything works, so obviously I saved my password for the account somewhere in Gmail.

I want to log in to Yahoo now, but cannot remember the password nor the security question.

Can I somehow pull the password from Gmail?

I already tried to find it in Firefox's and Chrome's saved password list, but could not find it there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

Instead...

> Reset your forgotten password
>   Forgot your Yahoo account's password?
>   Don't worry, just use our [Password
>   Helper](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot/) to reset your password and
>   regain access.

**References**
[Change or reset your Yahoo password - Yahoo Help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN2047.html)